# Synonymize [push-api] and [web-push]

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [push-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push-api) and [web-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-push) have [identical](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/push-api/info) [tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-push/info). There are about 200 total questions between the two tags.

While the official name in the W3 documentation is "Push API" I suggest that either [web-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-push) or a new tag such as [web-push-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-push-api) be the parent tag to differentiate from mobile device push notification systems.

Comment: AFAIK, is a working draft, it isn't even stable. Who's asking questions about this?

Comment: @Braiam there are ~200 questions, so I would say _users_.

Comment: @TinyGiant good, if they are users and not developers, maybe we should send them to another site.

Comment: So if people use _this_ site, we should send them elsewhere? That makes sense @Braiam

Comment: @TinyGiant if they have questions about Stack Overflow, obviously the site is meta.SO ;P

Comment: Why would people using this site asking questions about the experimental web push api be asking questions on meta? You're not making any sense. @Braiam